# Altium Designer Multiple Component Simultaneously Movement

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I am working with AltiumDesigner. Assuming that i have 10 component include 3*track, 2*via, 3*fill and 2*chip, now I want to move everyone 10 mm to the right. this is important to exact 10mm or any specific value. if i select and then move with drag this specific value does not materialized. I hope I conveyed my point correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: You should capitalise proper nouns (brand names, etc.) properly to make clear what you are talking about.

Comment: Set your 'global snap grid' to exactly how far you want to move the selected items, then press CTRL and whichever arrow key is in the direction you want. (Or maybe it's "shift",  don't recall ATM)

Answer (score 2):

You can select all the objects you want to move and than go to Edit -> Move -> Move Selection by X,Y...

In the dialog window that opens, you can specify the values by which you want to move the selected objects.

You can also use the hotkey combination E -> M -> X to navigate faster trough the menus. (You have to press the keys after each other, not at the same time.)